# How to insert white space with imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick

What parameters does "convert" (?) need to get this OUTPUT from this INPUT?

INPUT:

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I didn't want the images flush with the right side, I had to use a different approach (ImageMagick's `composite` tool):

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:white canvas.png
convert canvas.png in.png -geometry +200+200 -composite out.png
```

`-size` should be the final image size you want, `canvas.png` is a blank white canvas, `in.png` would be the image you want to pad, and `-geometry` is the positioning offset.

Answer (score 24):

My ImageMagick version is '6.7.8-0 2012-07-04 Q16'. According to the docu the answer of @kev command should work:

```
 convert in.png -gravity east -extent 520x352 out.png
```

However, like with most ImageMagick questions, you can achieve the same goal with different means. You could use `montage` like this:

```
 montage null: in.png -tile 2x1 -geometry +17+0 out1.png
```

This uses the special 'null:' image to concatenate it with the `in.png`.

---

It is true that with `convert` you need to re-compute the values you need to pass to `-extent` for each input picture that's got a different size.

First use `identify -format` to get the dimensions of the image:

```
 identify -format '%Wx%H' in.png
```

This should return something like:

```
 449x352
```

Ok, now you would need to add your wanted 71 pixels, to get the final `520x352` value. But you don't need to do that calculation in your own brains:

**ImageMagick to the rescue!, and its magic calculation capabilities...**  :-)

You can tell the `identify -format` command to do that calculation for you:

```
 identify -format '%[fx:W+71]x%H'
```

This should now give you a result of:

```
 520x352
```

So assuming you want to just pad/add a 'white strip' of 71 pixels width to the left of any picture, you can use the following single commandline:

```
 convert \
    in.png \
   -gravity east \
   -background white \
   -extent $(identify -format '%[fx:W+71]x%H' in.png) \
    out2.png
```

Voila! One commandline (which encapsulates 2 commands, to be honest) and you can let this one loose on all your PNGs, JPEGs, GIFs,... in a directory to auto-magickally add your 71pixels white strip to each of them:

```
 for i in *.png *.jpeg *jpg *.gif; do
    convert \
       ${i} \
      -gravity east \
      -background white \
      -extent $(identify -format '%[fx:W+71]x%H' ${i}) \
       $(convert ${i} -format "71-pixels-padded-left---%t.%e" info:)
 done
```

For each image its output remains the same filetype. Of course you can enforce all output to be PNG (or whatever you want). Just replace the `%t.%e` part of the command with `%t.png`...

Answer (score 9):

Documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#extent

```
convert in.png -gravity east -extent 500x352 out.png
```

Comment: Thanks!! But what if my picture is not 500x352 - because the size varies?

Comment: I just show you how to.

Comment: @kev: Your command doesn't exactly do what @gasko peter wanted. You should have used `-extend 520x352`. +1 for the 'right direction' though  :-P

Comment: sed 's#-extend#-extent#g'

Comment: I had to add `-background transparent` to preserve a transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I have this command defined in my `.bash_profile`. It will automatically compute the final image size from the padding you want in width and height (works with zeros):

```
# arithmetic with awk
calc() { awk "BEGIN { print $* }"; }

# pad an image
img_pad() {
    local width height pw ph 
    [ $# -lt 3 ] && { echo "Usage: img_pad <Input> <WxH> <Output>"; return; }

    # parse current size and padding
    IFS=x read width height <<< "$(identify "$1" | awk '{print $3}')"
    IFS=x read pw ph <<< "$2"

    # new widht and height
    width=$(calc "$width + 2*$pw")
    height=$(calc "$height + 2*$ph")

    echo "Converting '$1' to '$3' with size ${width}x${height} (+w=${pw}, +h=${ph})."
    convert "$1" -gravity center -extent "${width}x${height}" "$3"
}
```

Example usage:

```
# pad 50px left and right, no vertical padding
img_pad in.png 50x0 out.png
```